# How do I populate a drop-down list with List<string> using knockout.JS

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

I'm playing around with knockoutJS and am struggling to get a drop-down populated with data from my model.

I'm guessing I need to convert the model data to a JSON first but for the life of me can't figure it out.

I have a basic class:

```
public class QuoteViewModel
{
    public QuoteViewModel()
    {
        QuoteLines = new List<QuoteLine>();
    }

    public int QuoteHeaderId { get; set; }

    public string QuoteNumber { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Customer")]
    public SalesCustomer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }
    public List<string> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<QuoteLine> QuoteLines { get; set; }    
}
```

I have an ActionMethod in a controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreateQuote()
{
    QuoteViewModel quote = new QuoteViewModel();
    quote.QuoteNumber = "";
    quote.Status = "P";
    quote.Customers = _dbContext.SalesCustomers.Select(x => x.CustomerName).ToList();
    quote.QuoteLines = new List<QuoteLine>();

     return View(quote);
}
```

And the View():

Razor:

```
<select class="form-control" id="SelectedCustomer" data-bind="options: availableCustomers, optionsText: 'CustomerName', value: SelectedCustomer, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

ViewModel:

```
function QuoteViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Id = ko.observable('@Model.QuoteHeaderId');
    self.QuoteNumber = ko.observable();
    self.Status = ko.observable('@Model.Status');
    self.DateCreated = ko.observable();

    self.availableCustomers = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Customers)');


    @*$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "Test")',

        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                self.availableCustomers.push(new Customer(value));
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    });*@
    self.SelectedCustomer = ko.observable();

    self.QuoteLines = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.AddQuoteLine = function (sku, description, bomDetails) {
        self.QuoteLines.push(new QuoteLineViewModel(sku, description, bomDetails));
    }

    self.SaveToDatabase = function () {
        var dataToSend = ko.mapping.toJSON(self);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateQuote", "Test")',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

The commented out code uses ajax to get the customers and push it onto the array and that works, but is there not a way to do it directly from the model data?

Edit 1:

I don't need access to the whole SalesCustomer object, just the string name:

If I change my code as such:

Controller:

```
 quote.Customers = _dbContext.SalesCustomers.Select(x => x.CustomerName.Trim()).ToList();
```

Model class property:

```
 public List<string> Customers { get; set; }
```

Razor:

```
<select class="form-control" id="SelectedCustomer" data-bind="options: availableCustomers, value: SelectedCustomer, optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Javascript:

```
 self.availableCustomers = ko.observableArray([]);
 var customers = '@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.Customers))';
 self.availableCustomers = JSON.parse(customers);
 self.SelectedCustomer = ko.observable();
```

Now the drop-down is populated with the string values of customer names. However the selected customer is not passed back to controller on POST?

Edit 2:

Well I'm not sure why its working now, but it is.

The code is the same as in Edit 1.

The only thing I can think of is I was that I erroneously had the SelectedCustomer property type still set to SalesCustomer which will obviously not work:

```
public SalesCustomer SelectedCustomer { get; set; }
```

when it should be:

```
public string SelectedCustomer { get; set; }
```

Thank you user3297291 for the assistance in pointing me in right direction.

Comment: The way your `options` binding is set up indicates that `availableCustomers` should be an array of objects, not strings. Did you try removing `Select(x => x.CustomerName)` from your `Model.Customers` property? If you want to work with just string customer names, you have to remove the `optionsText` binding...

Comment: would it be correct then to haev my property is List<SalesCustomer> Customers {get; set;}, and then use self.availableCustomers = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.Customers)');

Comment: I'd expect that to work, but can't be sure having not seen your `SalesCustomer` model. Try it out and you'll know soon enough! P.S. if you need to later update the `availableCustomers` via AJAX, make sure it's an `observableArray`.

Comment: If you only inject the names of the customers, the client will not have the whole models to post. If you need to post the whole model, you should *use* the `optionsText` binding. Also, make sure to set observables like so: `self.availableCustomers(JSON.parse(customers))`